# Socket.IO server only accessible locally

Tags: javascript, server, socket.io

I have a Socket.IO server (Node.js, NPM) that works fine, but the problem now is that it only works in LAN.

I'm using Socket.IO 2.1.1.

My IP is my IPv4 address, and the port is 80. Here is my server.js code.

```
var express = require('express');
//var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

//App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(80, function() {
    console.log('listening to request on port 80! Yay!');
});

//Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //stuff to do on connection
}
```

and for the client

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.254.7:80', {transports:['websocket']});
```

and I also included

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://<ipv4>:80/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

where IPv4 is the IP address i'm using.

How do I make it public? (not only locally / LAN) I've tried changing

```
io.connect('http://192.168.254.7:80', {transports:['websocket']});
```

to

```
io.connect();
```

I've even changed the port from 3000 to 8080, and to 80.

I let my friends try to access the website, and it always shows
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Does it even load to the other's device?

Again, how do I make this public? Thanks.

Comment: so how do i get my public one

Comment: The problem is - how do i connect? I still need to use my 192.168.*.*, but it wont connect to socket.io properly. if i use my public IP, it will say ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Comment: it does work in LAN if my client-side code isn't connecting to socket.io via my public IP.